# Riddle: What the Rock Glimpsed

Tags: riddle, word

Here's my first attempt at a puzzle.  The answer is a word.

> A tawny pelt stretched toward the sky
>   It reached ground long after it died
>
> My zestful hearts were next to fall
>   Our blood spread thin amidst it all
>
> Our culture was the last to go
>   Torn apart before they zapped the whole
>
> Don't ask who, instead ask why
>   And find the answer simple as pie

Comment: a raised eyebrow and the question, "can you perceive what the rock has glimpsed?"

Comment: I can detect the rock's culinary preparations...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a

> pizza

```
A tawny pelt stretched toward the sky
It reached ground long after it died
```

> Traditionally pizza crusts ("tawny pelt") are tossed in the air to stretch them

```
My zestful hearts were next to fall
Our blood spread thin amidst it all
```

> Tomato sauce is definitely the blood.  The zestful hearts could be tomato pieces or maybe pepperoni slices. (The more I look at this, the "hearts" become unclear to me.  Artichoke hearts are also possible pizza toppings.)

```
Our culture was the last to go
Torn apart before they zapped the whole
```

> Shredded mozzarella ("culture" refers to cheese cultures, and it is "torn apart") is added before the pizza is baked quickly at high temperatures ("zapped")

```
Don't ask who, instead ask why
And find the answer simple as pie
```

> Pizza is often called a "pie" or "pizza pie"

edited to add: I forgot to mention the title.

```
What the rock glimpsed
```

> Pizzas are often baked on a pizza stone

Comment: Very good!  I tried to add several sets of redundant clues.  You solved the poem very well (even though I had something different in mind for lines 1&2).  Can you find the dead giveaway in Line 7?  (The title also has an alternate pun-ny clue, though it requires a particular piece of knowledge.)

Answer (score 2):

Since I already gave away the checkmark, I'll reveal the other clues here:

> First Clue: As Daphne B said, the first three stanzas describe a pizza, with the first of the couplet referring to the ingredient and the second the preparation:
>  -Wheat Fields/Ground into flour once the grain is dried
>  -Tomatoes/Spread as sauce in the middle
>  -Cheese/Shredded on top and cooked
>
>  Second Clue: The 7th line tells you that it is not a people, even though it sounds that way.  It also tells you to ask "why."  If you take every letter appearing after a "Y" in the poem, you will find the letters spell *p-i-z-z-a*.
>
>  Third Clue: 8th line.  As Daphne observed, 'pie' = 'pizza pie.'  Pretty easy.
>
>  Last Clue: The title has 2 clues, one tangential the other very obscure.  As Daphne said, it could refer to a pizza stone.  Also, the name "Peter" means Rock.  So what "The Rock glimpsed" is what "Pete saw."  Pete-Saw.  Pizza.  Get it?  :P (Ok.  That last one is a real groaner, but I don't consider clues in the title to be necessary.  They are just for a little extra fun.)

Thank you to Daphne B for the excellent answer, GentlePurple Rain for biting on the mislead, f'' for the correction, Manshu for the edit, and for all the viewers who took the time to think about it.  Happy Puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

This makes me think of Canadian (or American) [First Nations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Nations).

*A tawny pelt stretched toward the the sky

It reached ground long after it died*

> This could refer to a teepee, which is made of animal hide, which requires time to process before it can be "stretched toward the sky".

*My zestful heart was next to fall

Our  spread thin amidst it all*

> This could refer to animal blood used to decorate the teepee.

*Our culture was the last to go

Torn apart before they zapped the whole*

> This could refer to the way European colonists suppressed and actively destroyed the First Nations culture, including the [residential schools](http://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/residential-schools/).

*Don't ask who, instead ask why

And find the answer simple as pie*

> Not too sure what this means. Is it referring to the reasons for the European cultural oppression?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is not the correct word.  I realize the first 3 stanzas would seem to indicate a people/nation (a "who"), but that is not the case.  The actual answer is much less consequential than the poetic obfuscation would imply.

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

> An apple or some sort of fruit.

Comment: Welcome.  Don't forget to put your answers behind spoiler tags (see the help menu on the side) and explain your answer.